# I have to make an iPhone app that communicates with devices that support Modbus Protocol

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, modbus

I have to be able to communicate wirelessly which means it would either be MODBUS TCP/IP over wifi or MODBUS RTU over bluetooth. I cannot find any modbus implementations with an objectiveC wrapper, but I can write the wrapper over a C library. How should I go forward?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the Bluetooth method: the iPhone can only talk to devices that use the iPhone Accessory Protocol over Bluetooth.

Wifi should work though. Using the C wrapper will also work: objective-C is a superset of C, so you should be able to use the library unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem you can buy an [anybus box](http://www.anybus.com/support/support.asp?PID=413&ProductType=Anybus%20Serial%20Server) to connect the device to the network and then use this [library](https://github.com/iUtvikler/ObjectiveLibModbus) to connect to it.

To communicate through Bluetooth you can use BLE and RedBearLab library but probably need to create the frames yourself. I'll update my answer if I find a library for that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the problem. Can you elaborate?

Thanks.